# Bolt: Getting blank screen after upgrading to 2.2beta

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm getting a blank screen when trying to access all parts of the site (back and front). Here's the error log:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Bolt\\Content::setValues() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/feral/src/Content.php on line 410 and defined in /var/www/html/feral/src/Content.php on line 245, referer: http://localhost/feral/
```

Here's the config.yml for the theme:

```
templatefields:
    templates/home.twig:
        subheading:
            type: text
        feature_section_heading:
            type: text
        feature_section_text:
            type: textarea
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `/src/Content.php`, line 406, change:

```
if ($unserdata !== false) {
```

to:

```
if ($unserdata !== false && is_array($unserdata)) {
```

I can't reproduce it yet, so this is untested..